# cursor.fetchall() in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

After saving some data in a variable with `cursor.fetchall()`, it looks as follows:

`mylist = [('abc1',), ('abc2',)]` this is apparently a list.

That is not the issue.

The problem is that the following doesn't work:

```
if 'abc1' in mylist
```

it can't find 'abc1'. Is there a way in Python to do it easily or do I have to use a loop?

Comment: ``mylist`` is a list of tuples and ``'abc1'`` is a member of the tuple. ``'abc1' in mylist`` will be ``False`` because ``mylist`` has a _tuple_ ``('abc1',)``

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` returns a row list, i.e., a list containing rows.

Each row is a tuple containing column values. There is a tuple even when there is only one column.

To check whether a row is in the row list, you have to check for the *row* instead of the column value alone:

```
if ('abc1',) in mylist
```

Comment: Oh man. I knew it was something that simple. My god I tried eth but didn't think of changing that criteria. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is problem with using `select *` statement.

Instead use `select col1,col2 from table_name`

Below code might help

```
sql = "select col1,col2,col3 from table_name"
cursor.execute(sql) # initialize cursor in your way
input_dict = dict( (row[0],(row[1],row[2])) for row in cursor.fetchall() )
```