# How do I print a value without any brackets or commas or parenthesis?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I want to print out only the value without any brackets or commas or parenthesis. I am using MySQL with python with mysql.connector.

When I run this code I get "('esrvgf',)". But I want to just get "esrvg".

[image]

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="password",
  database ="mydatabase"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()


sql = "select nick from users where ipaddress = '192.168.1.4'"

cursor.execute(sql)

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're getting a tuple.  Try `print(*x)`, or `print(x[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997387/cursor-fetchall-in-python)), not a string. If you try to print a tuple you Python will add parentheses, and if you try to print a list Python will add brackets. All you need to do is print the first element with `x[0]`. Like this:

```
for x in myresult:
  print(x[0])
```

Alternatively, you can use the `*` operator to pass every element of the tuple as a parameter to `print()`. Like this:

```
for x in myresult:
  print(*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [.fetchall()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) you won't get a single element returned even if there's only one, per the documentation:

> The method fetches all (or all remaining) rows of a query result set and returns a list of tuples. If no more rows are available, it returns an empty list.

Therefore, consider using:

```
for x in myresult:
  for y in x:
     print(x)
```

Or, if you are certain it's a single element:

```
for x in myresult:
   print(x[0])
```